# Holder's inequality. Proof using conditional extremums .Need help, can't see how one step is found.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Prove:$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i\leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^p)^{1\over p}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^q)^{1\over q} $$ $(a_i\geq0,x_i\geq0,i=1,..n,p>1, {1 \over p}+{1\over q}=1)$

Let $u=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^p)^{1\over p}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^q)^{1\over q} $ with the condition that $A=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i, A=const.$ We form the Lagrange function|: $$L=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^p)^{1\over p}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^q)^{1\over q}+ \lambda(A-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i)$$ , And we make the system of linear equations: $$L_{x_j}'=x_j^{q-1}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^p)^{1\over p}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^q)^{{1\over q}-1}-\lambda a_j=0, j=1,..n $$ Now without losing generality we can supose : $x_i >0, a_i>0(i=1..n)$ Dividing the j-th equation in tthe system with equation m (also in the system), we get : $$({x_j \over x_m})^{q-1}={a_j\over a_m}$$ From there, with a fixed $m$ we find that: $x_j=x_m({a_j \over a_m})^{1\over q-1}, j=1..n, j\neq m. (2)$ Applying now $(2)$ to the equation we get: $$\sum_{i=1,i\neq m}^{n}a_ix_m({a_i\over a_m})^{1\over q-1} +a_mx_m=A$$ or
$$**{x_m\over a_m^{1\over q-1}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{q\over q-1}=A.**$$. Now how does one justify this last line?? I'll type the rest of the proof out for educational purposes, just this linhe is unclear to me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $x_i=x_m({a_i \over a_m})^{1\over q-1}$ holds for all $i$ including $i=m$, so:
$$
A=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_m({a_i\over a_m})^{1\over q-1}
={x_m\over a_m^{1\over q-1}}
\sum_{i=1}^na_ia_i^{1\over q-1}
$$
Now add the exponents on $a_i$: $1 + {1\over q-1}={q\over q-1}$.